# Subscribe standard SQS to an FIFO SNS Topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

In our system, an SNS topic has several subscribers, each one of them doing different processing on the messages.

For some of the subscribers, the order in which the original events occurred and as they were received through the SNS is significant. So the SNS topic was created as FIFO and the order-sensitive subscribers use FIFO SQS.

For the other subscribers, the order does not matter and duplication is acceptable, so those would prefer to use standard SQS to avoid the [higher FIFO queue prices](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/#:%7E:text=How%20are%20Amazon%20SQS%20requests%20priced%3F) and [other restrictions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/quotas-queues.html).

However, AWS seems to allow subscribing only

- FIFO SQS to FIFO SNS
- Standard SQS to Standard SNS

Why does not AWS allow subscribing standard SQS to FIFO SNS, as it seems to be simply relaxing the ordering requirement after the messages arrive in SQS?

Are there any workarounds? I see a few suggestions of using lambda to receive messages from SNS and send them to SQS but that means additional costs for lambda execution.

Is there any effort in progress to support this scenario?

[image]

The CloudFormation also returns similar error:
`Invalid parameter: Endpoint Reason: Please use FIFO SQS queue`

Comment: It looks like you'll need to use a FIFO SQS queue. Is there any problem with doing that?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, we would prefer to use standard SQS to avoid the [higher FIFO queue prices](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/#:~:text=How%20are%20Amazon%20SQS%20requests%20priced%3F) and [other restrictions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/quotas-queues.html). Also since the order does not matter to us, the standard queue correctly represents it. On the other hand FIFO would give a wrong impression.

Comment: Based on the information presented in the screenshot, it appears that you have no choice unless you want to write a Lambda function to receive the message and re-send it to the SQS queue.

Comment: Note that you can't even subscribe a Lambda function to a FIFO SNS topic - the only protocol available is FIFO SQS. Thus you'd need FIFO SNS -> FIFO SQS -> Lambda -> Standard SQS. Slightly ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

The corresponding feature was just released Sep 14 2023: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/09/amazon-sns-fifo-topics-message-delivery-sqs-standard-queues/. You can now subscribe standard SQS to an FIFO SNS Topic

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).